# part of panda3d actor not rendered correctly

Tags: python, 3d, render, panda3d

I have been working on a little ego shooter for a few days now. Basically what I've got together is just a simple test map, a character (rigid and animated) and some movement logic.

Everything works fine when the character is loaded as a static model, however, when loaded as Actor with animations, the head does not get displayed when looking at it directly. It's just invisible.

The head becomes visible again whenever you look at some point above the character, but otherwise it is just not there.

Here are some images showing the problem:
[image: missing head]

and here how it look from just a little different angle:
[image]

Any help is greatly apprechiated.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question using just the information given.  Perhaps sharing the model would work.  Also, keep in mind you don't happen to have any scale of 0 set on any of the bones.

Comment: @rdb I see... I'll upload the model as soon as I get to it. What do you mean by "any scale of 0 set to any of the bones" though?